# How to let text in JLabel continue off the label (right)?

Tags: java, excel, text, alignment, jlabel

I don't want to start a new line in the jlabel, i know i can do that with html.

If have multiple panels or labels lined up left to right, how can i let the text in the center label continue off the label and show up on top of the right label? Kind of like in excel sheets when there isn't anything to show in the cell to the right.

Answer (score 0):

> Kind of like in excel sheets when there isn't anything to show in the cell to the right.

Swing components are not designed to overlap one another.

If the text of the label is truncated you can set the tool tip text of the label to the text of the label. Then when the mouse hovers over the label the tooltip will display the entire text.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("with some long text to display");
label.setToolTipText( label.getText() );
```

If you truly want the components to overlap by some predetermined fixed amount the you can try using the [Overlap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/) which is designed for this purpose.

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to do it without the tooltiptext?

Comment: @a.kumar, I was just updating the answer with a second suggestion.